# Generic/unknown HTTP error when using unity 2017

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unitywebrequest

I want to send and get data from my server using UnityWebRequest from unity 2107.4

I tried using code from [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1586470/how-do-i-get-into-the-data-returned-from-a-unitywe.html)

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class WebRequestExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Where to send our request
    const string DEFAULT_URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";
    string targetUrl = DEFAULT_URL;

    // Keep track of what we got back
    string recentData = "";

    void Awake()
    {
        this.StartCoroutine(this.RequestRoutine(this.targetUrl, this.ResponseCallback));
    }

    // Web requests are typially done asynchronously, so Unity's web request system
    // returns a yield instruction while it waits for the response.
    //
    private IEnumerator RequestRoutine(string url, Action<string> callback = null)
    {
        // Using the static constructor
        var request = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);

        // Wait for the response and then get our data
        yield return request.SendWebRequest();
        var data = request.downloadHandler.text;

        // This isn't required, but I prefer to pass in a callback so that I can
        // act on the response data outside of this function
        if (callback != null)
            callback(data);
    }

    // Callback to act on our response data
    private void ResponseCallback(string data)
    {
        Debug.Log(data);
        recentData = data;
    }

    // Old fashioned GUI system to show the example
    void OnGUI()
    {
        this.targetUrl = GUI.TextArea(new Rect(0, 0, 500, 100), this.targetUrl);
        GUI.TextArea(new Rect(0, 100, 500, 300), this.recentData);
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(0, 400, 500, 100), "Resend Request"))
        {
            this.StartCoroutine(this.RequestRoutine(targetUrl, this.ResponseCallback));
        }
    }
}
```

and [cs_getannounce](http://209.97.161.99:8080/PHONjQ0YjNkNzkyNzgwZTliYjY0NjZmMDNhNZ+TgxBdko+EGKm3rRDlVMb/tgG1nuNn6MkmgWopZhQ5v9eq5uwJnf/Q5DabNnaiCtcobx7rvAd69T+XoE3X/KZKI9S738dftEtGL526IFqFX2NtAK8p5j3IyfFSRzF0mzczMWViOGM5NGI2MjFiYQ==) , [cs_login](http://209.97.161.99:8080/PHOMDZlNzRlOWFkZWQzOTE0MWY3Y2E4MDY1MM/uVmPxOW4y27nASHBHPFe4fqOCPT7OMLinsVEZ8bZkJaADz5qiH6ZRKAUlIO3AXH096pl6mnORUSgFJSDtwFxGACCHVdFu1VTp37t5xKNQRd8wjtAVtR2pIgCVIIblHt6cDaxguXdOu05UMS+aCZo60YIzPrAofSIaX4UoefVT1eVkjnuzdh6dtzDsAtGy6vLDFYTu/iXOlJ318Z7xnq4GV/mlokvJFVE0BgfEinTrFjqrrwX4TJGJyfaWcxhANjYyMzE5MmIzNDhmOWRkMQ==) , [cs_zonelist](http://209.97.161.99:8080/PHOODcyNzZhYjU5NWIxYzA1MjFiOGVmNWEzZGannUS2ARndfdm1QNM2YWAXugET7NSy+RrybRpMMNZgnuPXtRko01G4MnhmwY3M4ROxnef3w1UKI70bK2KkSP3Qr2Xo8ff/7pF3PPC/TP0P7CJcHnpLqRoPZyOKSc7jKl8PSqjo//bB42vD0/Ye+WIsiW7CX1J5EI9Pp1M8D/vqTZG7B6G/Hh9KmPaFvaYXLFLrwS1C8OYq129j0y/DVIMDqlyCVu54NCgjV0j+XX1Vk2aFxAu+nVRINTavXN9kAYlDtRCb0D2gY+p35AUsjuPJQHXnJATBQPVur0IINe0RNTJjMjRiMWY2Nzk1MjY3) is the link that I tried to access

it should get data with all three links provided, but only cs_getannounce and cs_login can, while cs_zonelist cannot (get an error 403). I tried using unity 2018 too but no luck. When I use unity 2019, it works. But I really have to use 2017

Comment: All three [worked for me](https://imgur.com/a/BE1BtDQ) using an empty project with just your code and Unity `2017.4.31f1`

Comment: @derHugo I cannot access imgur, please upload it somewhere else

Comment: Why can't you access it? Is it possible that in general your internet access is a bit strange? https://drive.google.com/open?id=1i0bsO77mL1c5jFmsQlondWyn3xeeG-6a

Comment: @derHugo imgur blocked in my country :(